# Cannot get first frames using avformat_seek_file

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavformat

I want to seek for an arbitrary frame in a video using `libav`. More precisely, using the function `avformat_seek_file`, which apparently uses `av_seek_frame` internally.

I want to make a backward search (i.e. to get the closest possible frame *before* the one I seek), so that I can then go forward until I find *precisely* the one I want. For this, I use the function as follows:

```
avformat_seek_file(..., ...,
                   std::numeric_limits<boost::int64_t>::min(),
                   target_pts,
                   target_pts,
                   ...);
```

Which means that I don't have any tolerance about finding a frame that comes after my target_pts, but I am happy with any frame coming before.

I am using the [Big Buck Bunny videos](http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/index.php/download/) for testing. Using the 480p H.264 video, I can seek any `pts` without problems. But using the 480p OGG video, I can't. Actually, I can seek for any frame after `pts = 73`, but not before. Seeking for `pts = 0` sets the video to `pts = 73`.

One might think that the stream actually begins at `pts = 73`, but this is not what `<stream>.start_time` returns. Moreover, if I only load the video and read the frames in order, I can get the first 73 frames without any problem. The issue is that I can never come back to one of those frames by using `avformat_seek_file`.

Last point: if I use the flag `AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY`, then it works. But that might result in me decoding only a part of the frame I want, which is not a solution for me.

Can anybody explain this weird behavior?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution/explanation for this? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be an old question but this answer is for people who are having the same problem.

The old `av_seek_frame` function uses the `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` flag to seek to frames with a time stamp smaller than or equal to the target time stamp. By default this function will seek to frames with a time stamp equal to or greater than the target time stamp. The documentation of the new `avformat_seek_file` function indicates that this flag is ignored.

> If flags contain AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY, then non-keyframes are treated as
>   keyframes (this may not be supported by all demuxers). If flags
>   contain AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD, it is ignored.

As we can see in the source code below.

```
2156     if (s->seek2any>0)
2157         flags |= AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY; 
2158     flags &= ~AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD;
```

The problem occurs when the `avformat_seek_file` function falls back on `av_seek_frame`, as you mentioned, and needs to set the `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` flag again. This happens only if the difference between the target time stamp and the minimum time stamp is larger than the difference between the maximum time stamp and the target time stamp.

```
 2187     // Fall back on old API if new is not implemented but old is.
 2188     // Note the old API has somewhat different semantics.
 2189     if (s->iformat->read_seek || 1) {
 2190         int dir = (ts - (uint64_t)min_ts > (uint64_t)max_ts - ts ? AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD : 0);
 2191         int ret = av_seek_frame(s, stream_index, ts, flags | dir);
 2192         if (ret<0 && ts != min_ts && max_ts != ts) {
 2193             ret = av_seek_frame(s, stream_index, dir ? max_ts : min_ts, flags | dir);
 2194             if (ret >= 0)
 2195                 ret = av_seek_frame(s, stream_index, ts, flags | (dir^AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD));
 2196         }
 2197         return ret;
 2198     }
```

In other words, `ts - min_ts` overflows because you're using the smallest int64 value which ensures that the `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` flag will never be set. Why not use zero instead?